# How to get textbox value that are inside of while loop?

Tags: php, mysql

I have textbox that are query from database. I show this textbox from while loop.

```
$ans_no = 0;
 while($ed_ans_row = mysql_fetch_array($ed_ans_query)) {
   $edit_answer = $ed_ans_row['name'];
   $edit_id = $ed_ans_row['id'];
   echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"ans[]\" class=\"ans\" value=\"$edit_answer\" /><br/>";
   echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"edit_id[]\" class=\"ans\" value=\"$edit_id\" />";
  }
```

Now, I want to save this pair of answer and id into database like this:

```
UPDATE table SET answer='ans[0]' WHERE id='edit_id[0]';
```

But I don't know how many textbox are query from database. And how to update this answer and id together correctly.

I don't have a lot of experience in php. Thanks for every reply.

Comment: what is the value of `$ans_no`??

Comment: you can post form to get value.. and also use ajax for this

Comment: I don't want to use ajax

Comment: how about `name=\"ans-".$edit_id."\"`. it will be easier later on when trying to save.

Comment: yes, but I want to know how to I retrieve this each of ans-$edit_id. because ans- is static and $edit_id is different for each other. right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create your text box with names name[]

```
<input type='text' name='name[]'>
```

Get values like that :-

```
$name= $_POST['name'];
$N = count($name);
for($i=0; $i < $N; $i++)
{
echo($name[$i]);
}
```

Comment: And how do I add this array into each variable. Please can you show me sample. Because I don't have a lot of experience in php. Thank you.

Comment: $name= $_POST['name'];
$N = count($name);
for($i=0; $i < $N; $i++)
{
echo($name[$i]);
}

Comment: get value like that @NightMare

Answer (score 0):

You can say:

```
$i = 0;
$answers = array();
while(isset($_POST['ans-'+$i])){
    $answers[$i] = $_POST['ans-'+$i];
    $i++;
}
print_r($answers);
```